# Hide or Show element on menu

Tags: javascript, html, onsen-ui

I have this on my html doc

```
<ons-splitter>
        <ons-splitter-side id="menu" side="left" width="220px" collapse swipeable>
          <ons-page>
            <ons-list>
              <ons-list-item onclick="fn.load('home.html')" tappable>
                Home
              </ons-list-item>
              <ons-list-item onclick="fn.load('altaVehiculo.html')" tappable>
                Alta de Vehículo
              </ons-list-item>
              <ons-list-item onclick="fn.load('busquedaTalleres.html')" tappable>
                Búsqueda de Talleres
              </ons-list-item>
              <ons-list-item onclick="fn.load('registroMantenimiento.html')" tappable>
                Registro de Mantenimiento
              </ons-list-item>
              <ons-list-item onclick="fn.load('listadoMantenimientos.html')" tappable>
                Listado de Mantenimientos
              </ons-list-item>
            </ons-list>
          </ons-page>
        </ons-splitter-side>
        <ons-splitter-content id="content" page="home.html"></ons-splitter-content>
      </ons-splitter>
```

I want to hide some of the **ons-list-item** by default (on the window.fn.open = function() ), and then when the user logs in successfully show them.
What would be the **Js** code for that? (just the hide part, and show, the login and validation is already done)

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Look into `document.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: create an onclick function for log in that grabs all your elements `document.querySelectorAll` and sets them to display show `element.style.display = "show";` Make sure they're set to `display:none` by default

Comment: Tks, I will try to do that.